# Tome of Battle: Strikes and Weapon Properties

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dungeons-and-dragons, tome-of-battle

I'm making a Warblade and I'm wondering if I get my weapons properties on all my maneuvers that initiate a melee strike. For example, Steel Wind or Mithril Tornado, would I get my Vicious weapon property damage (to them and myself) to ALL targets hit? What about stuff like Mountain Hammer? It adds damage dice to an attack it initiates, does that damage stack with my weapon's flaming or frost?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, yes, you add your weapon properties on all your maneuvers since part of initiating them is making melee attacks.

Comment: Wow, that's rather broken for stuff like Mithral Tornado. Thanks. I'll have to be careful with Vicious. I have Vampiric to balance it out but it still might come out uneven and leave me with less HP. It's take a d6, heal a d6. The damage could be 6 and the healing 1...

Comment: @Snowpaw *Mithral tornado* is a 4th-level strike, meaning you have a minimum of BAB +7/+2, and two attacks against one target is generally better than one attack against two. If you have three or more people around you, *mithral tornado* is better than a full-attack, but it’s also a class feature – it *should* be better than what you can do by default. Plus getting yourself surrounded on a regular basis is... not that great a choice.